# LaSalle statement - Find a positive function

Tags: real-analysis, control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I am looking for a function with certain properties. They follow:

- Consider a mapping $\mathbf{f}: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbf{R}$, positive definite, and $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ is the greatest compact which $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) = 0$. The question is if exists a mapping $\mathbf{g}: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) = x_1 \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x})$.

It is all I know. I thank in advance.

Best regards.

-- Edit --
Consider the dynamical system below. Fo so, find u that stabilizes the system on $(0, 0)$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\dot x_1 &=& x_1^3 + \sin(x_2) \cos(x_1) + u \\
\dot x_2 &=& -x_1 x_2 \cos{x_1}
\end{eqnarray*}

My approach was to find a Lyapunov control function that stabilizes the system on the origin according to Ljapunov function $V(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2$. Than.

\begin{equation}
u = \frac{1}{\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}^{\intercal} g} (- \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}^{\intercal} f + \phi(x))
\end{equation}

Then, $\dot V(x) = -\phi(x)$. The function may satisfy the LaSalle conditions i.e. the greatest compact set of $\dot V(x)$ is 0. Furthermore, $u$ is always finite.

Comment: I don't know what "greatest compact" means. But doesn't $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ satisfy the hypotheses but not the conclusion?

Comment: Indeed. The greatest compact mean a set roughly that it has no holes or any other singularity, like a ball completely filled or a line. Due to conditions of the theorem I require to fulfill (LaSalle Invariance Theorem namely), it means ONLY the origin (0,0) (for 2D) can be zero, for certain function . There are other ways to state it: for example, since $\mathbf{f}$($\mathbf{0}$) = 0 and $\mathbf{f}$($\mathbf{x}$) = $x_1 * \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x})$, than, by L'Hôpital's law, $\lim_{\limits_{\mathbf{x} \to (0, 0)} \frac{\partial\phi(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_1} = 0$.

Comment: I can't read the last part of the comment, the TeX is broken, but are you saying that $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ shows $g$ doesn't exist?

Comment: $\lim_{\mathbf{x} \to (0, 0)}  \frac{\partial \phi(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_1} = 0$. Since g is not unique, the function $\mathbf{f}$ you provided says it does not exists. But I am not sure if a function exists which fits the provided properties.

Comment: Given $f$, isn't $g$ uniquely defined by $g(x,y)=x^{-1}f(x,y)$? I don't understand how you can agree that $g$ does not exist, and then write that you are not sure whether such a $g$ exists.

Comment: For given f, $\mathbf{0}$ is not the greatest compact set.

Comment: But $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is zero if and only if $(x,y)=(0,0)$. I thought that was what you wanted – see your first comment.

Comment: So, where do we stand on this, Bruno?

Comment: Are you still here, Bruno?

Comment: Sorry, I am late. I will go with this. The issue with this approach is that $x^{-1} f(x, y)$ might be a singularity, which is, in practical cases, inconvenient. However, I thank you sincerely for the concern.

Comment: OK, so, you want $g$ to be defined (and, presumably, continuous) on all of ${\bf R}^2$.

Comment: I reddited if it makes the problem clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V(x) = x^2_1 + x^2_2$, the time derivative of $V(x)$ is

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x} &= \nabla V \cdot f(x)  \\
 &= \left[\frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x_2}\right] \left[f_1(x),f_2(x)\right]^{T} \\
 &= \left[2x_1,2x_2\right][x^3_1+\sin x_2\cos x_1 + u \ , \ -x_1x_2\cos x_1]^{T} \\
&= 2x^4_1 +2x_1\sin x_2\cos x_1 + 2x_1u - 2x_1x^2_2\cos x_1 \\
&= 2x^4_1 +2x_1\cos x_1(\sin x_2-x^2_2) + 2x_1u  \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Now let us choose $u=-2x^3_1-\cos x_1(\sin x_2 - x^2_2)$ and substitute it in Eq(1), we get

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{V}(x) &= 2x^4_1 +2x_1\cos x_1(\sin x_2-x^2_2) + 2x_1u  \\
&= 2x^4_1 +2x_1\cos x_1(\sin x_2-x^2_2) + 2x_1 \Big[-2x^3_1-\cos x_1(\sin x_2 - x^2_2)\Big] \\
&= 2x^4_1 +2x_1\cos x_1(\sin x_2-x^2_2) - 4x^4- 2x_1\cos x_1(\sin x_2-x^2_2) \\
&= -2x^4_1 \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

With our choice of $u$, indeed $\dot{V}(x) \leq 0$ plus $V(x)$ is positive definite, therefore, the origin is stable in the sense of Lyapunov. Unfortunately, Lyapunov theorem doesn't allow us to draw any conclusion about the **asymptotic** stability because $\dot{V}(x)\leq 0$ (i.e negative semi definite). Using LaSalle theorem, we can show asymptotic stability (i.e. having $V(x)$ positive definite and $\dot{V}(x)$ negative semi definite) if we can show that $\dot{V}(x)$ does not vanish identically along any trajectory in $\mathbb{R}$, other than the null solution $x=0$. We can show that by setting $\dot{V}(x)$ to zero, hence
$$
\dot{V}(x) = -2x^4_1 \implies 0 = -2x^4_1  \implies x_1 = 0 \implies \dot{x}_1 = 0 \tag{3}
$$

From the system's equations, we check

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= x^3_1 + \sin x_2 \cos x_1 + u  \\
\dot{x}_1 &= x^3_1 + \sin x_2 \cos x_1 + \Big[-2x^3_1-\cos x_1(\sin x_2 - x^2_2)\Big]  \\
\end{align}
$$
From Eq(3), we see that if $x_1=0$ then $\dot{x}_1=0$, hence:

$$
\begin{align}
0 &= 0 + \sin x_2 (1) + \Big[0-(1)(\sin x_2 - x^2_2)\Big]  \\
0 &= 0 + \sin x_2  - \sin x_2 + x^2_2   \\
0 &= x_2
\end{align}
$$

$\dot{V}(x)$ does not vanish identically along any solution other than $x = 0$,
and the origin is asymptotically stable by LaSalle Theorem (i.e. the stability here is locally). Moreover, since $V(x)$ is radially unbounded (i.e. $V(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $||x|| \rightarrow \infty$), the origin is globally asymptotically stable.

Comment: You owe my most sincere thanks, sir!